# Issue with upgrade to php7 and new mysql

Tags: mysql, php7

I upgraded everything from nginx to php to mysql and everything is configured correctly seeing as i can install a fresh version of joomla, but my previous project is now showing a blank page, no errors on nginx logs, php logs or joomla logs. The only thing i can see is that the new joomla installation is using innodb engine on the database and utf8mb4 coallation while my previous project is using mylsam and utf8 general. I have tried to run this query to convert all the tables to innodb but it doesnt even convert them after success. So my question is split into two, am i missing something thats giving me a blank joomla, and is this query if successful going to resolve the issue im facing. Thank you in advance.

SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE joomlaDB.', TABLE_NAME,' ENGINE=InnoDB;') 
FROM Information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'joomlaDB' AND ENGINE = 'MyISAM' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, then you need to enable error reporting. Open your **configuration.php** and set `$error_reporting` to `development`. Please report back with the errors you see once done.

Comment: yes its all enabled, its on development, set to 1 in configuration, in htaccess, php ini, php7 configuration and i am getting no errors.

Comment: Well a blank page means there are errors but they're not being displayed. May be worth a google search on how to display them on your setup

Comment: Ok thank you for your time, by any chance do you think a corrupt database could cause a blank page without any errors?

Comment: Even if there was something wrong with the database, an error would appear. There's definitely something on your setup that is preventing them from being displayed. Perhaps take a backup of your site and install on a localhost

Comment: ok thank you. I will see if using nginx has different methods of using htaccess to report the errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40989/discussion-between-brigitte18-and-lodder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are no errors, and your facing white or blank site on front end or back end only one thing worked for me which is renaming the plugins folder (making back end work) and renaming it back while renaming each individual folder inside plugins one at a time to find what is suppressing the errors or over writing the error reporting.